# Can I use Free Energy as reconstruction error when I use RBM to anomaly detection?

Tags: anomaly-detection, restricted-boltzmann-machine

Can I use Free Energy as reconstruction error when I use RBM to anomaly detection?

If Free Energy of a sample more a threshold, can I regard it an outlier?

How to explain Free Energy of RBM?

Answer (score 0):

I thought you can refer to this paper: [Energy-Based Anomaly Detection for Mixed Data](https://truyentran.github.io/papers/outlier_kais17.pdf) for more details.

In that paper the author states that:

> Under this energy-based framework, anomalies have higher free-energy
>   than the rest.

So to answer your question:

> Can I use Free Energy as reconstruction error when I use RBM to anomaly detection?

Yes.

> If Free Energy of a sample more a threshold, can I regard it an
>   outlier?

Yes, you can.
[image]

> How to explain Free Energy of RBM?

In RBMs, free-energy equals the negative log-density up to an additive constant, and thus
offering a principled way for density-based anomaly detection. And its function is:

$$F(x) = -log \sum_h exp(-E(x, h))$$